# Recovering pem file connection rejected after ebs volume attach/detach new EC2 instance

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys, pem

**Objective:**

*lost pem file - recover connection for aws ec2 instance*

**what i tried:**

```
As per most of Stack overflow Answers, 
1) created new intstance
2) detach volume of lost instance and attach to new one
3) ssh to new instance, mount, copied keys, and umount 
4) attach volume to original instance
```

Guide given in the link
[Recover pem file](http://blog.celingest.com/en/2013/11/14/replace-lost-keypair-ec2-instance/)

But using the new key, i could not get logged in

```
port 22: Network is unreachable
```

Any help pls?

Comment: Did the instance's IP address change when you stopped and started it?

Comment: yes. IP address changed when i did so.

Comment: And you are now trying to access it on the new IP address, and there are no firewalls on your side that might prevent this?

Comment: I am sure, there are no firewalls.

Comment: If the instance is passing its health checks, and you followed the other steps correctly, then there is not a clear explanation for what you are seeing.

Comment: steps followed on as per the documentation, it gives the expected result on every step except final  ssh -i .......

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106573/discussion-between-ramamoorthy-villi-and-michael-sqlbot).